# asynchronous udp server client application

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to make an asynchronous UDP chat application, currently having only one client and server.

When I run my server, a lot of redundant data is displayed. Afterward, when some text is typed,

> Error sending the file!

is displayed.

Could someone please look at the code and let me know where I am going wrong?

Server:
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(sd,FIONBIO,&iMode);
    int n=sd+1;

```
fd_set readfds,writefds;
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_SET(sd,&readfds);
    FD_SET(sd,&writefds);

    int rv = select(n, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL);
    if(rv==-1)
    {
        printf("Error in Select!!!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(rv==0)
    {
        printf("Timeout occurred\n");
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds))
    {
        FD_CLR(sd,&readfds);
        int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        int bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer,SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
        if (bytes_received < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive datagram.\n");
            closesocket(sd);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    printf("\nClient says: %s",buffer);
    printf("\nWrite :");

    fgets(buffer,SIZE,stdin);
    if(FD_ISSET(sd,&writefds))
    {
        FD_CLR(sd,&writefds);
        int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if(sendto(sd, buffer,strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client,client_length)<0)
        {
            printf("Error sending the file! \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
closesocket(sd);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you don't need to manually clear the socket from the sets (e.g. the `FD_CLR` calls). You reset the sets anyway before the `select` call.

Comment: Secondly don't use `&buffer` in your `memset` call. If `buffer` is a pointer it won't do what think it does. Also, if `buffer` is a pointer then `sizeof(buffer)` will return the size of the _pointer_ not what it points to.

Comment: What does WSAGetLastError return after the failed call to sendto?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,buffer is the name of the array...

Comment: Thirdly, if a function fails then you should print out the value of [`WSAGetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you know _what_ went wrong.

Comment: And lastly, there is nowhere in the code you shown that prints `"Error Transmitting data"`. Is this the correct code you show us?

Comment: the value reutrned by WASGetLastError is "10047"...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,I am so sorry:( my bad,the error is "Error sending the file"...

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem.  This line:

```
int rv = select(n, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL);
```

Will nearly always return immediately with the readfds empty.  But writefds will almost **ALWAYS** be set with the "sd" socket indicating that it is ready for writing/sending.

Hence, your code correctly skips the attempt to call recvfrom(), but nothing stops it from falling through to the sending code path.  All of the variables such client, client_length, and buffer as are likely uninitialized at that point.  Or worse, buffer and client are exactly what they were from the last successful call in the loop. That likely explains the redundant data.

My advice would be to not have a "writefds" set in the select call at all. Then only "send" when you actually read. The sendto call won't block for any significant amount of time anyway.

Comment: @ selbie,sorry it does remove redundant data from the server but does not solve my problem:(

Comment: in fact the situation is such that the client writes for a while then stops,on the server side if I write something the message sent by  the client is dispayed but nithing happens on the client side...